# Mongo query item from subarray, having trouble

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm relatively new to mongodb, and I came into this company's set up that had the database already set up and running.  It looks to me like the structure of this "array" isn't actually a proper array.  They are saving info that I need in "offer_info_array" - which then has a nested array with an "offer id" which changes a lot between records, and then nested inside that is the info that I need to select.  Here is an example of a record.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52041af3bbf8057203000004"),
    "offer_info_array" : {
        "128" : {
            "affid" : "68",
            "s1" : "YJF"
        }
    },
    "city" : "Cleveland",
    "state" : "OH",
    "zip" : "44111"
}
```

So from a whole db of records like this one, I need to find all records that have the "affid" of "68" - I realize this database is not structured correctly, but there's not much I can do about that for records that already exist.  The "128" is the offer id that varies from record to record.

If anyone has any insight and can help me out with this, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that in a query, but $elemMatch might be of help. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch

Comment: This is a great example for why not to use field names to contain dynamic data.  You'll have to use map-reduce or just stream the whole collection into your program and manually go through each doc and iterate over each `offer_info_array` field looking for matching `affid` values.

Comment: I agree Johnny, I hate the fact that the previous programmer inserted all these records with a dynamic field name in the offer_info_array.  thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/#op._S_where) operator which accepts JavaScript function:

```
db.items.find({$where: function() { 
                         for(var key in obj.offer_info_array)
                             if(obj.offer_info_array[key].affid == 68)
                                return true;
                         return false; }})
```

This function looks for properties of `offer_info_array` object and gets value of property by key. Then we verify if property value has `affid` property equal to 68. If yes, we return `true` which means objects matches our query. If there is no properties with `affid` equal to 68, we return `false`.

Keep in mind, that $where operator do not use indexes.

Comment: Thank you lazyberezovsky!  That actually works very well.  Of course as expected, the query is very slow over a large database, but it still returned a count for me and I got what I needed.  Thank you very much